# PHP: image with echo not showing the echo word just the image

Tags: php, image, echo

A script can get a image stored and display it on .php like example:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

my problem is when I put something like

```
echo 'a word here';
```

it shows the image but the echo part is not showing. there's a possible solution about this? like i don't want to put the image script to other .php file and read it on the other .php script. I want the image and the echo in the same script page. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an `echo` statement whilst you have set the header as an image. 

**Alternate Solution:**
You can make use of PHP GD library to write text on the image though.

Comment: i know what if i remove the header and i put it a function and call the function on echo <img scr="test();" /> the problem is still the same. there's any possible solution?

Comment: Why don't you give a try ?

Comment: This works though.. But this will be a plain HTML `<?php
echo "<img src='img1.jpg'>";
echo "Hello World";`

Comment: no I want to have the script file imagecreatefrompng when I output it i can add some echo text, buttons, forms, etc.

Comment: I have told you in the answer that you can't. Image cannot have buttons, forms.. HTML rendering is the only way like as in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
<img src="myimg.png" alt="yeehaw">
```

Comment: nooo i need the code with creatimage and put some echo like when the image has been output i want to echo some text or buttons etc. or forms

Comment: sorry @shankar i think we crossed streams there... myel, that is what html does.  php gets the data from the server, html presents it in the browser.  no reason to mess with the header